# How to dynamically create multiple Flexslider slideshows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider this code:

```
<?php foreach ($objVideos as $objVideo) : ?>

    jQuery('#carousel-<?php echo $objVideo->id; ?>').flexslider({
       animation: "slide",
       controlNav: false,
       animationLoop: false,
       slideshow: false,
       itemWidth: 223,
       itemMargin: 25,
       asNavFor: '#slider-<?php echo $objVideo->id; ?>',
       selector: ".slides > li",
       prevText: "",
       nextText: ""
    });

    jQuery('#slider-<?php echo $objVideo->id; ?>').flexslider({
       animation: "slide",
       controlNav: false,
       animationLoop: false,
       slideshow: false,
       sync: "#carousel-<?php echo $objVideo->id; ?>",
       selector: ".slides > li",
       prevText: "",
       nextText: "",
     });


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you can see I am using a PHP loop to create multiple slideshows.  Each time through the loop of several videos (I'm not displaying videos in Flexslider.  These are slides that go with the video.).  I'm wondering if there's a way to mark up the HTML so I can avoid the loop.  Some kind of jQuery selector, I guess.  But I'm not sure how to pass a variable into the Flexslider so I can sync the slideshow and the thumbnails.  Here is WooThemes' markup for the HTML.

```
<!-- Place somewhere in the <body> of your page -->
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide4.jpg" />
    </li>
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="slide1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="slide4.jpg" />
    </li>
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried using a class, but then I can't figure out how to sync the thumbnails to the main image.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I feel so stupid.  A Javascript loop is what I needed.  Duh.

```
jQuery('.image-container').each(function(index) {
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('data-container');
    jQuery('#carousel-' + id).flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 223,
        itemMargin: 25,
        asNavFor: '#slider-' + id,
        selector: ".slideshow > li",
        prevText: "",
        nextText: "",
    });

    jQuery('#slider-' + id).flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: false,
        sync: "#carousel-" + id,
        selector: ".slideshow > li",
        prevText: "",
        nextText: "",
    });
});
```